# Combine multiple "import * as <name> from '<path>' which contains multiple export const into 1 export for index.js

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have 2 files let say `filters.js` and `utils.js`. Both contains multiple `export const` like below:

**utils.js**

```
export const formatDate = (
  value,
  formatting = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' }
) => {
  if (!value) return value
  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', formatting).format(new Date(value))
}

/**
 * Return short human friendly month representation of date
 * Can also convert date to only time if date is of today (Better UX)
 * @param {String} value date to format
 * @param {Boolean} toTimeForCurrentDay Shall convert to time if day is today/current
 */
export const formatDateToMonthShort = (value, toTimeForCurrentDay = true) => {
  const date = new Date(value)
  let formatting = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric' }

  if (toTimeForCurrentDay && isToday(date)) {
    formatting = { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric' }
  }

  return new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', formatting).format(new Date(value))
}

// Strip all the tags from markup and return plain text
export const filterTags = (value) => value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, '')
```

**filters.js**

```
export const title = (value, replacer = ' ') => {
  if (!value) return ''
  const str = value.toString()

  const arr = str.split(replacer)
  const capitalizedArray = []
  arr.forEach((word) => {
    const capitalized = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1)
    capitalizedArray.push(capitalized)
  })
  return capitalizedArray.join(' ')
}

export const avatarText = (value) => {
  if (!value) return ''
  const nameArray = value.split(' ')
  return nameArray.map((word) => word.charAt(0).toUpperCase()).join('')
}
```

Now, in my `index.js`, I want to combine the 2 and export it again. Here's my not working code

```
import * as Filters from './filters'
import * as Utils from './utils'

export { Filters, Utils }
```

This compiles okay and I can use `import {avatarText } from '@utils'` where I just alias the `@utils` for their path.

The import avatarText wont work and doing a debug, it shows this result

[image]

each of the Module their contains the array of the method I put as `export const`.

What shall I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you already tried:

```js
// index.js
export * from './filters'
export * from './utils'
```

Note that in this case you must not have name collisions.